# Salesforce Error Publishing Community 1715759908

Tags: force.com-sites, error-messages, community-builder, experience-builder-page, experience-bundle

I created an Experience Site in a developer sandbox. Once it was ready, I deployed the experience Bundle, Site, Network and all related metadata (LWC, Aura Components, Classes, Fields, etc.. ) to a partial sandbox for UAT testing.

Everything is there and looks good in the experience builder with all the proper settings.

When I try to publish the community from the builder or through SFDX command, I get the following error:

> An error has occurred while processing your request. The
> salesforce.com support team has been notified of the problem. If you
> believe you have additional information that may be of help in
> reproducing or correcting the error, please contact Salesforce
> Support. Please indicate the URL of the page you were requesting, any
> error id shown on this page as well as any other related information.
> We apologize for the inconvenience.
>
> Thank you again for your patience and assistance. And thanks for using
> salesforce.com! Error ID: 2074602639-22792 (1715759908)

I have compared the two communities / settings etc. between the sandboxes and they are identical. I also have researched for similar issues online but have not found this error id and nothing I have tried seems to work.

Has anyone run into this issue before? Do you how to fix this so I can successfully publish the Experience Site?

Comment: You should report this to Salesforce Support.

Comment: I opened a ticket with Salesforce Support. Hopefully they can generate some logs, but from my experience, they never help. I wanted to reach out to the community to see if anyone experienced this and also will post an answer here if / when I resolve

Comment: This is also happening to me, exact same problem, when migrating from one ORG to other ORG.

Comment: what template? Is it a build your own (LWR) template?

Comment: In my case Build your Own (Aura)

Comment: Mine was also Build your own (Aura)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Salesforce Support got back to me and they said that this was most likely caused because during the deployment, Navigation Menu Item records were created without having a DraftRowId set.

**As a solution:**

perform the following query and see if there are any records that are returned.

```
SELECT DraftRowId,Id,Label,NavigationLinkSetId,NavigationLinkSet.NetworkId,ParentId,Status,Target,Type 
FROM NavigationMenuItem 
WHERE Status = 'Live' AND DraftRowId = null
```

If there were records returned, delete them. Once I deleted them, I was able to successfully publish the site in the Experience Builder.

You can verify that the Navigation Menu Items belong to your experience by comparing the
*NavigationLinkSet.NetworkId* to the NetworkId for your Experience Site.

Comment: That worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks it worked for me aswell.

If you want to see on which community you're deleting the navigation menu item from you can add this field to the SOQL NavigationLinkSet.Network.Name.

So :
SELECT DraftRowId,Id,Label,NavigationLinkSetId,NavigationLinkSet.NetworkId,ParentId,Status,Target,Type,NavigationLinkSet.Network.Name
FROM NavigationMenuItem
WHERE Status = 'Live' AND DraftRowId = null